# How to download file from a URL and save/replace it in a folder using Java 8?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-8, nio

So, I need to download 2 csv files which include pricing details for some AWS services.

```
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AWSStorageGateway/current/index.csv
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonS3/current/index.csv
```

I need to download the files from the URLs and store it in separate folders to avoid conflicts. Such as, the first index.csv file will be downloaded to a folder **AWSStorageGateway** and the second one to folder **AmazonS3**.

Or another approach could be to store those files in 1 folder by changing filenames like **AWSStorageGateway.csv** and **AmazonS3.csv**. If the files already exist, it needs to be replaced with the new one.

The project uses Java 8 and Spring MVC. I don't want to use any external libraries. Is NIO package enough to handle this?

Comment: I think you can do that in pure java. With spring and nio, you can definitly do this task.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-can-i-download-and-save-a-file-from-the-internet-using-java

Comment: @Donatic The Files.copy worked for me. Thanks for that